# What would be the correct mongo query for this

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need help to make a mongo query for the data

```
Employee{
history:{
    include:
        [{type,value},{type,value}]
    },
    exclude:
        [{type,value},{type,value}]
    }
```

}

In the above data I need to fetch employees that contain include.type C or P with values 1,2,3 and should not contain exclude.type A or B with values 2,4,6

I used the following query

```
  $and: [
    {
      $or: [
        { "history.include.type": "C", "history.include.value": { $in: [1, 2, 3] } },
        { "history.include.type": "P", "history.include.value": { $in: [1, 2, 3] } }
      ]
    },
    {
      $or: [
        { "history.exclude.type": "A", "history.exclude.value": { $nin: [2, 4, 6] } },
        { "history.exclude.type": "B", "history.exclude.value": { $nin: [2, 4, 6] } }
      ]
    }
  ]
})

Sample Data:
Employee{
    history:{
        include:[
            {
                type:A,
                value:1
            },
            {
                type:B,
                value:2
            }
        ]},
        exclude:[
            {
                type:C,
                value:1
            }
            
        ]}
}

I have records matching the criteria but the query does not return teh desired output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          "history.include": {
            $all: [
              { $elemMatch: { type: "C", value: { $in: [1, 2, 3] } } },
              { $elemMatch: { type: "P", value: { $in: [1, 2, 3] } } }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "history.exclude": {
            $not: {
              $elemMatch: {
                $or: [
                  { type: "A", value: { $in: [2, 4, 6] } },
                  { type: "B", value: { $in: [2, 4, 6] } }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**